# Continuous hatch line needed in canvas with repeated pattern

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to build a hatch pattern using a combination of canvas and kinetic and I am having issues trying to get a continuous line.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uW8xz/126/) shows what I have so far, but because my repeat pattern is a sqaure the corners are affecting the line, I have tried using the lineJoin and lineCap properties, but cannot seem to get the desired result.

The main code in question is this:

```
var hatchPattern = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = hatchPattern.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 20);
context.lineTo(20, 0);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

I have created another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uW8xz/160/) which although not perfect, will probably do for me, still not sure why there is a slight gap though!

Comment: **About your update:** You must fill the top-left & bottom-right corner with a triangle. These triangles will fill in the beveled corners caused by your center line coming to a point at top-right & bottom-left. See my updated answer for example code showing your thinner, more angled diagonal lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create diagonal lines covering your canvas, you can create a pattern like this:

You must fill the top-left & bottom-right corner with a triangle. When repeated as in a pattern, these triangles will fill in the beveled corners caused by your center line coming to a point at top-right & bottom-left

[image]

Then `createPattern(yourPattern,"repeat")` will pattern-fill the canvas like this:

[image]

**Here's example code and a Demo showing thinner lines:**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var p = document.createElement("canvas")
p.width=32;
p.height=16;
var pctx=p.getContext('2d');

var x0=36;
var x1=-4;
var y0=-2;
var y1=18;
var offset=32;

pctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
pctx.lineWidth=2;
pctx.beginPath();
pctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
pctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
pctx.moveTo(x0-offset,y0);
pctx.lineTo(x1-offset,y1);
pctx.moveTo(x0+offset,y0);
pctx.lineTo(x1+offset,y1);
pctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle=ctx.createPattern(p,'repeat');
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @markE it isn't quite what I am after, I have added another fiddle to my question which has got me a lot closer to what I want.

Comment: It wont work well with larger linewidth of around pctx.lineWidth=10;. Can you update this with the fix?

Comment: @Rayiez. Use bigger stripes in the pattern and the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/jxskbph3/) will have bigger stripes. :-)

Answer (score 10):

markE's code doesn't produce a 45º-angle pinstripe pattern (in fact, it doesn't match that of his example png image), so I ended up rewriting it to generalise it.

**Code snippet:**

```js
/** Creates a canvas filled with a 45-degree pinstripe.
  * @returns the filled HTMLCanvasElement. */
function createPinstripeCanvas() {
    const patternCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const pctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d', { antialias: true });
    const colour = "#B4645D";

    const CANVAS_SIDE_LENGTH = 90;
    const WIDTH = CANVAS_SIDE_LENGTH;
    const HEIGHT = CANVAS_SIDE_LENGTH;
    const DIVISIONS = 4;

    patternCanvas.width = WIDTH;
    patternCanvas.height = HEIGHT;
    pctx.fillStyle = colour;

    // Top line
    pctx.beginPath();
    pctx.moveTo(0, HEIGHT * (1 / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH * (1 / DIVISIONS), 0);
    pctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    pctx.lineTo(0, HEIGHT * (1 / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.fill();

    // Middle line
    pctx.beginPath();
    pctx.moveTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT * (1 / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH * (1 / DIVISIONS), HEIGHT);
    pctx.lineTo(0, HEIGHT);
    pctx.lineTo(0, HEIGHT * ((DIVISIONS - 1) / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH * ((DIVISIONS - 1) / DIVISIONS), 0);
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH, 0);
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT * (1 / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.fill();

    // Bottom line
    pctx.beginPath();
    pctx.moveTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT * ((DIVISIONS - 1) / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH * ((DIVISIONS - 1) / DIVISIONS), HEIGHT);
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    pctx.lineTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT * ((DIVISIONS - 1) / DIVISIONS));
    pctx.fill();

    return patternCanvas;
}

/** Fills the whole area of a given htmlCanvasElement with a patternCanvas.
  * @param targetCanvas – the HTMLCanvasElement to fill into.
  * @param patternCanvas – a HTMLCanvasElement containing a pattern to fill with.
  */
function fillWithPattern(targetCanvas, patternCanvas){
    const ctx = targetCanvas.getContext('2d', { antialias: false, depth: false });
    const width = targetCanvas.width;
    const height = targetCanvas.height;
    if (!width || !height) throw new Error("progressCanvas's width/height falsy.");

    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    return targetCanvas;
}

fillWithPattern(document.getElementById("targetCanvas"), createPinstripeCanvas());
```

```css
#targetCanvas{border:1px dotted black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="targetCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Jamie Birch's answer; however, I found it difficult to change the angle of the lines.

This is how I solved the problem:- using a while loop to generate a number of diagonal lines, shifting the start and end point of each line each time.

```
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const max = 15; // The number of stripes
    let i = 0;
    let x = 0;
    let z = -180; // The incline of stripes

    while (i < max) {
        // Draw diagonally top-right to bottom-left
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, -10); // Start 10px above the top of the canvas to get around line caps
        ctx.lineTo(z, canvas.height + 10); // Finish 10px below the bottom of the canvas to get around line caps
        ctx.lineWidth = 24; // Stripe thickness
        ctx.strokeStyle = rgb(0,0,0);
        ctx.stroke();
        x += 60; // Shift origin for start of next stripe
        z += 60; // Shift destination for end of next stripe
        i++;
    }
```